# Add a click functionality to sidebar without affecting its toggle feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, togglebutton

I have a sidebar and I have a button which toggles the sidebar on click. I have a jQuery function which does that. I have a new functionality now, where, if the sidebar is open and the user clicks any of the list items in the sidebar, it toggles back and some function will be excecuted.

*The Problem:*

When I click the `li` inside the sidebar, the toggle button is waiting for it's second click (my guess). So if I add toggle on clicking sidebar `li`, the main toggle button functionality breaks. How do I keep both without affecting each other. I hope I have made myself clear. Here is the code.

**JS**

```
// code for sidebar toggle in jQuery
$.fn.toggleClick = function () {
    var methods = arguments,
        count = methods.length;
    return this.each(function (i, item) {
        var index = 0;
        $(item).on('click', function () {
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};

//for opening sidebar
function openSidebar() {
    $('#sg-evm-sidebar').animate({
        left: 0
    }, 300)
    $('.container').css({
        position: "fixed"
    }).animate({
        left: 300
    }, 300)
    $('.content-overlay').delay(300).show();
}
//closing sidebar
function closeSidebar() {
    $('#sg-evm-sidebar').animate({
        left: -300
    }, 300)
    $('.container').css({
        position: "fixed"
    }).animate({
        left: 0
    }, 300)
    $('.content-overlay').delay(300).hide();
}

//$(".empName").on("click", function () {
//   closeSidebar();
//});

// calling toggleclick here
$('.toggle-box').toggleClick(openSidebar, closeSidebar);
```

Here is a [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/qvksx30g/). I created it from my huge website. So please ignore broken images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvksx30g/4/

I've added some basic logic

```
var sidebarOpen = false;

function toggleSidebar()
{
    if (sidebarOpen)
        closeSidebar();
    else
        openSidebar();
}
```

And then inside `openSidebar` and `closeSidebar` I set `sidebarOpen`.

I also no longer use `toggleClick`. Instead I'm using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-box', toggleSidebar)
  .on('click', '.list li', closeSidebar);
```

Comment: Your fix is awesome. But still I have some issues after I click for the third time on my site. It keeps toggling in and out. I am refreshing the sidebar using handlebars each time. may be that's the issue. I ll try it from here and let you know. Thanks for your help. `Boolean's` are beautiful.

Comment: See the update. Using `$(document).on` attaches event listeners to the document rather than DOM elements that are changing.

Comment: Works absolutely fine now. Thanks a lot @jcuenod for the extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of the sidebar state (open or close) using a class on the sidebar wrapper ("close" or "open"), and then use this class to determine in your click listener if you have to call closeSidebar or openSidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will consider it.